# Find a number $x$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^x}{2^n n!} = \frac{1539}{64}e^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, transcendental-equations

I need to find a number $x$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^x}{2^n n!} = \frac{1539}{64}e^{1/2}.$$
What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Run and hide? :)

Comment: Start with $x=0$, then $x=1$, then $x=2$, continue until you can guess the pattern.

Comment: It looks like for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ numerators give [OEIS A004211](http://oeis.org/A004211). I wonder, if there is a closed form for a fractional $x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One may note that
$$\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^a\;\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}}_{e^{z}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^a z^n}{n!}.$$
Now indeed setting $a=6$, calculating the derivatives of $e^z-1$ and setting $z=\frac12$ in the final expression, we get $\frac{1539}{64}\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Exponential_function),
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n^k z^n}{n!} = e^z T_k(z),$$
where $T_k(z)$ is the $k^\text{th}$ [Touchard polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials). Using $z = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and $k = 6$, we find
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n^6}{2^n n!} = e^{1/2} T_6(1/2) = \frac{1539}{64}e^{1/2}.$$

(Hopefully someone can find a more satisfying solution.)

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that this sum can be computed if $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $f_0(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} \frac{x^n}{2^n n!}$. This is a power series; its radius of convergence is infinite, and we have $f_0(x) = \exp\left(\frac x2\right)$.
For all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_{k+1}(x) = xf_k'(x)$. 
By induction, it is straightforward to show that 
$f_k(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} \frac{n^k x^n}{2^n n!}$.
Let $P_k(x) = 2^k \exp\left(-\frac x2\right)$, so that
$$f_k(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} \frac{n^k x^n}{2^n n!} 
= 2^{-k} \exp\left(\frac x2\right) P_k(x)$$
We have $P_0(x) = 1$, and the relation $f_{n+1}(x)=xf_n'(x)$
yields immediatly $$P_{n+1}(x)=x\bigl( P_n(x) + 2P_n'(x) \bigr).$$
One can compute $P_1(x)=x$, $P_2(x)=x^2+2x$, ..., $P_6(x) = x^6+30x^5+260x^4+720x^3+496x^2+32x$.

For $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have
$$\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{n^k}{2^n n!} = f_k(1)
= \exp\left(\frac 12\right) \frac{P_k(1)}{2^k}. $$

Now is time for a bit of luck:
the denominator is $64=2^6$ and $P_6(1)=1539$.

Hence $x=6$ is solution.